# Views are transitioning individually/separately when using Activity Transitions

Tags: android, slide, android-transitions, activity-transition

I'm trying to create a slide up effect for one of my Android Applications' Activity, similar to the Gmail app's compose Activity enter animation/transition, without the previous Activities' exit animation though. As per my research, there are two ways to achieve this:

1. `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.stay)` after startActivity() in Activity A and `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay, R.anim.slide_out_bottom)` after finish() in Activity B. Problem with this approach: I need to set listeners for the enter animation/transition in Activity B in order to perform further animations and I do **not** want to use some kind of guessed delay in onCreate(). Other than that, this approach works flawlessly.
2. Using the "new" (not really anymore) Activity Transitions API to perform a android.transition.Slide for both the enter and exit transitions of Activity B with the slide edge set to bottom. Problem with this approach: [This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6iwOSKaWdAWNUQ3YURtRmNlT2M) weird seperation / individual transitioning of views is introduced when using this approach. (Not pasting any code here as it's not necessary, I'm using the Slide from a transitionSet in xml or the default constructor in code)

So my question is, is there a way to have an actual listener for approach 1 I don't know of or is there a way to eliminate that weird separation with approach 2 and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the views that should be animated together in a "Transition Group".

Comment: Gonna try that out!

Comment: In general that works, I don't know how to have the status bar background share a TransitionGroup with the Activity contents though. Setting isTransitionGroup to true on the DecorView doesn't seem to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener for approach #1 using [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/). Basically, that is an event bus that provides a mechanism that you can use to communicate with different parts of your application.

Comment: I don't think it's worth adding that much (actually) redundant bloat/code to the app